# Is there any web portal which shows upload speed while uploading files?

Tags: internet, uploader, connection-speed

I want to upload some files. I can use [we transfer](https://wetransfer.com/) or [drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/en_GB/login) but the problem is all these web portal do not show upload speed. Is there any cloud storage where I can upload files and it also shows me the upload speed.?

The reason I need upload speed is because I have to show the upload speed to a client. I can normally test the upload speed using many online tools which shows upload speed of `~0.8Mbps` but when we upload any files, it take lot of time because I know the speed is no more than `100KBps`. So I need to show them that actual speed is in `KBps` not `Mbps`. Thanks

Comment: So there is no portal or website which can tell us the actual upload speed?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser to see if it now has it. I recall seeing something in the issues queue.

Comment: The other one I know is https://github.com/projectsend/projectsend . But this and https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser are for if you want to self-host. But check to see if they now have cloud solutions. If so, I can enter full answer.